# Spring batch dynamic reader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement in Spring Batch, the file name will be passed as input via arguments, if the file is present we need to read the file in chunks of 1000 or if file name is not passed then need to connect to oracle database and read all the records from a particular table

I have gone through documentation but not sure how to implement this

Note: the file will only contains id, enriching will be done in processor

Could some one please suggest or provide some sample code on how to implement the above functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a step scoped reader and return the required type based on the job parameter:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemStreamReader<Person> itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['file']}") String file) {
    if (file != null) {
        //return a FlatFileItemReader<Person> configured with the `file` parameter
    } else {
        // return a JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> or a JdbcPagingItemReader<Person>
    }
}
```

With that in place, you can run your job like:

- `java -jar myjob.jar`: this will use the jdbc reader
- `java -jar myjob.jar file=myfile.csv`: this will use the file reader

Comment: PagingJdbcItemReader uses sort keys and row number(ie:oracle) and reads chunk by chunk, I wanted to understand how flatfileitemreader works does it fetch all record at once or does it read from file based on chunk size ?

Comment: That's another question. Does this answer answers your initial question? You can return a JdbcPagingItemReader instead of the JdbcCursorItemReader if you want,

Comment: thanks for the answer . I will post a new question so that we can get to know how it works :)

Comment: No need for a separate question, the FlatFileItemReader will stream records from the file line by line without loading the entire file in memory. The chunk oriented step will buffer lines until chunkSize is reached, then it will call the processor/writer before moving to the next chunk, etc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own implimentation of `org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` with a file existence check and depends from the result return a Jdbc reader or File reader